# Microphone Streaming not clear

Tags: java, android, audio, stream

I have created an app which is supposed to stream audio from user's microphone. There are two parts in the app:

1. Android app
2. Java class for listening to the audio sent from app

**The problem which I am facing is that, the stream is happening, but the quality of the stream is very poor and there is also a noticeable interruption in the stream.**

**The Activity in android app:**

```
public class SendActivity extends Activity {
    private Button startButton, stopButton;

    public byte[] buffer;
    public static DatagramSocket socket;
    private int port = 50005;
    AudioRecord recorder;

    private int sampleRate = 8000;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig,
            audioFormat);
    private boolean status = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                status = true;
                startStreaming();

            }

        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                status = false;
                recorder.release();
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder released");

            }

        });

        minBufSize += 2048;
        System.out.println("minBufSize: " + minBufSize);
    }


    public void startStreaming() {

        Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                    Log.d("VS", "Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                    DatagramPacket packet;

                    final InetAddress destination = InetAddress
                            .getByName("192.168.1.20");
                    Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");

                    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                            sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat,
                            minBufSize * 10);
                    Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");

                    recorder.startRecording();

                    while (status == true) {

                        // reading data from MIC into buffer
                        minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                        // putting buffer in the packet
                        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,
                                destination, port);

                        socket.send(packet);
                        System.out.println("MinBufferSize: " + minBufSize);

                    }

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("VS", "IOException");
                }
            }

        });
        streamThread.start();
    }
}
```

**The layout file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SendActivity" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_button"
        android:text="Stop" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="79dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
        android:text="Start" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The java class for listening to the audio:**

```
class Server {

AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
static AudioInputStream ais;
static AudioFormat format;
static boolean status = true;
static int port = 50005;
static int sampleRate = 8000;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

    /**
     * Formula for lag = (byte_size/sample_rate)*2
     * Byte size 9728 will produce ~ 0.45 seconds of lag. Voice slightly broken.
     * Byte size 1400 will produce ~ 0.06 seconds of lag. Voice extremely broken.
     * Byte size 4000 will produce ~ 0.18 seconds of lag. Voice slightly more broken then 9728.
     */

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[9000];

    format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

    while (status == true) {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);

        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                receivePacket.getData());

        ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());
        //System.out.println("Reading...");
        toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());

    }
}

public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
    try {

        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        volumeControl.setValue(6.0206f);

        sourceDataLine.start();
        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        sourceDataLine.start();

        System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

        sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
        System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**What should I do to get a clear and continuous audio stream from the app to the class?**

Comment: _"the quality of the stream is very poor"_. When you record with an 8000 Hz sample rate, the results _will_ be poor. To get something that begins to sound decent you'll probably want to increase the sample rate to _at least_ 22050 Hz (this will of course increase the bandwidth usage).

Comment: thats fine can you provide me a list of sample rates for android?

Comment: You should try the common ones (8000, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, 48000) until you find one that works on the device your app is running on.

Comment: Any code suggestions on that?

Comment: Put them in an array and iterate over it beginning at the end; stop when you find a configuration that works.

Comment: should the server end also have the same sample rate?

Comment: If the server is going to process the audio it needs to know what sample rate, encoding, number of channels, etc it is using.

Comment: Audio is clearer now, but there is a periodical jitter which is making the audio unclear